# Glitch/disappearence of complete d3 chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am using below to remove and update my bar graph with new data but in doing so I am getting a small glitch/ the complete graph disappears for 1 sec till new data is loaded. But is it possible to do same by just increasing/decreasing bars without actually disappearing the chart.

```
d3.selectAll("svg").remove();
```

Comment: You can update data without removing the graph. http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8

Answer (score 1):

Below is the solution:

Add an id to the svg as stated in below example:

```
var svg = d3.select(".completion-chart").append("svg")
            .attr("id", "probar2")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
```

And then everytime you populate the same chart just add below code prior to redrawing the same chart as in above code:

```
d3.select("#probar2").remove();
```

Note: Do have a check point to remove the chart only if it exists.